# PHP: Overuse of date manipulation leading to convoluted code

Tags: php, datetime

I despise playing with dates in PHP so no doubt the below is too convoluted for what is needed. What I am looking for is a general tidy/reduction.

Everything but the `wednesday` and `friday` arrays are in a loop. The loop is from a ROQL statement. Oracle SQL for it's RightNow product, which is a very very stripped down version of MySQL from what I understand, meaning we are limited to basic SELECT statements i.e. we can't do anything worthwhile there.

1. `$inc['order_date']` is a string representing a date in the format yyyymmdd
2. `$inc['order_dispatch_date']` is a string representing a date in the format yyyymmdd
3. `$inc['order_address']` is a string representing an address

So the basics of the code is:

1. Loop through each row in the database
2. Convert some dates
3. If the order address in the database is in the `wednesday` array, set the collection date to the Thursday after
4. If the order address in the database is in the `friday` array, set the collection date to the Saturday after
5. Do some more date conversion/manipulation
6. **END GOAL:** Get the difference in days between the `order_date` and the `collection_date`

**CODE**

```
$wednesday = array("Paris","London","New York");
$friday = array("Munich", "Cardiff", "Sydney"); 

$res = RNCPHP\ROQL::query( "SQL QUERY HERE")->next();
while($inc = $res->next()) {        

    $order_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $inc['order_date']);
    $order_date = $order_date->format('Ymd');

    $order_dispatch_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $inc['order_dispatch_date']);
    $order_dispatch_date = $order_dispatch_date->format('Ymd');

    if (in_array($inc['order_address'], $wednesday)) {
        $order_collection = date('Ymd', strtotime('next thursday', strtotime($order_dispatch_date)));
    }
    if (in_array($inc['order_address'], $friday)) {
        $order_collection = date('Ymd', strtotime('next saturday', strtotime($order_dispatch_date)));
    }

    $order_collection = new DateTime($order_collection); 
    $order_date   = new DateTime($order_date);

    $interval = $order_date->diff($order_collection);
    $interval = $interval->d;
}
```

**FIRST REVISION**

```
if (in_array($inc['order_address'], $wednesday)) {
    $order_collection = new DateTime(date('Ymd', strtotime('next thursday', strtotime($inc['order_dispatch_date']))));
}
if (in_array($inc['order_address'], $friday)) {
    $order_collection = new DateTime(date('Ymd', strtotime('next saturday', strtotime($inc['order_dispatch_date']))));
}

$order_date = new DateTime(date('Ymd', strtotime($inc['order_date'])));
$interval = $order_date->diff($order_collection)->d;
```

Comment: I think maybe I am misunderstanding your task.  If the order falls on a Wednesday or a Friday, you want to the customer to pick it up 8 days later.  Isn't the diff always going to be 8 days if found in either array?  It seems you could skip some of these processes as soon as you know an order exists in one of the day arrays.  What is the default collection time for all other days? next day? or is it variable?

Comment: Can we see a sample input array? and the expected result? Seeing the loop structure may be helpful too.

Comment: @mickmackusa it's based on dispatch date -so if it's dispatched on a Wednesday for a Wednesday collection, it will be picked up on the following Thursday which is +1 day. Loop structure added but it won't add much

Comment: Good.  I just wanted to see that the arrays were declared outside of the loop.  Double quote `F`.

Comment: Where is the `$order_collection` declaration for non-Wed/Fri rows?

Comment: There is only ever Wednesday and Friday deliveries being made. The company gives a dispatch date and based on the location, the delivery is the Wednesday or Friday after that despatch date, but people can pick it up from the Thursday/Friday after at the earliest.

Fundamentally it works - I just needed it cleaning up

Comment: Now I am re-confused.  Are you saying every order_address exists in one of the two arrays?  If so, the second should be an else.  If not, then some rows will not declare a valid/intended `order_collection` variable.

Comment: Yes - I had an if/else there originally. Something broke, did it this way, fiddled around a lot and forgot to change it back

Comment: So which of my assumptions are true?  Is every order always in one of the arrays?

Comment: Yes - as mentioned, every order is in one of the two arrays

Answer (score 2):

I'll provide a snippet with some sample data to demonstrate a few of my suggested techniques.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ab9fff695a6c06147fe1f4a8ea865d81fe236d15))

```
$incs=[
    ['order_date'=>'20171128','order_dispatch_date'=>'20171129','order_address'=>'Paris'],
    ['order_date'=>'20171128','order_dispatch_date'=>'20171129','order_address'=>'Munich'],
    ['order_date'=>'20171129','order_dispatch_date'=>'20171130','order_address'=>'London'],
    ['order_date'=>'20171129','order_dispatch_date'=>'20171130','order_address'=>'Cardiff'],
    ['order_date'=>'20171130','order_dispatch_date'=>'20171201','order_address'=>'New York'],
    ['order_date'=>'20171130','order_dispatch_date'=>'20171201','order_address'=>'Sydney']
];

$wednesday = array("Paris","London","New York");

foreach($incs as $inc){
    $order_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymdhis', $inc['order_date'].'000000');
    $day_name = in_array($inc['order_address'], $wednesday) ? 'Thursday' : 'Saturday';
    $order_collection = new DateTime($adj_date=date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtotime("next $day_name {$inc['order_dispatch_date']}")));

    $interval = $order_date->diff($order_collection)->d;
    echo "\n{$inc['order_date']} - $adj_date = $interval";
}
```

Output:

```
20171128 - 2017-11-30 00:00:00 = 2
20171128 - 2017-12-02 00:00:00 = 4
20171129 - 2017-12-07 00:00:00 = 8
20171129 - 2017-12-02 00:00:00 = 3
20171130 - 2017-12-07 00:00:00 = 7
20171130 - 2017-12-02 00:00:00 = 2
```

Now for the fine points:

- Because you state that every `order_address` is in the `$wednesday` or `$friday` array, then you should only be checking one of them for best efficiency.  This check will determine the day name that will be fed to `strtotime()` later.
- When generating your DateTime objects, assign them zero-ed times.  This way php will not default them to the "current time" for the given date.  Performing this declaration will avoid getting deviations in the `diff()` value later.
- `strtotime()` will correctly interpret your `Ymd` format, so no additional string preparation is necessary.
- The syntax for your `strtotime()` call is a single parameter with `next` $day_name`and`$inc['order_dispatch_date']` all in a single string.
- You can sensibly save a line of code by chaining `->d` to your `$interval` declaration.

Here is how I think your new code should look:

```
$wednesday = array("Paris","London","New York");

$res = RNCPHP\ROQL::query( "SQL QUERY HERE")->next();
while($inc = $res->next()) {        

    $order_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymdhis', $inc['order_date'].'000000');
    $day_name = in_array($inc['order_address'], $wednesday) ? 'Thursday' : 'Saturday';
    $order_collection = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtotime("next $day_name {$inc['order_dispatch_date']}")));

    $interval = $order_date->diff($order_collection)->d;
}
```

Comment: @pee2pee I have updated my answer using the new details that you have provided.